# Function does not work when named function is supplied to it

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

I don't know why these two snippets of code don't produce the same result. In the first example I create a function and pass it and in the second example I write an anonymous function.

```
 function funct() {
        $("p").slideUp(1000);
 }
 $(document).ready(funct());

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").slideUp(1000);
 });
```

The second one works, the first one does not. Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$(document).ready(funct());
```

You are executing `funct()` immediately and passing it's return value to the `.ready()` method which is NOT what you want. It is not waiting for the document to be ready before the function executes.  What you probably meant to do is this:

```
$(document).ready(funct);
```

This way, you are just passing the function reference to the `.ready()` method and it can then execute the function later rather than immediately and it will then behave identically to the anonymous function example.

To execute a function immediately put parens after it like `funct()`.  To pass a function as a reference that can be called by the function/method you're passing it to, leave off the parens and just pass the name `funct`.

Answer (score 2):

To understand why this doesn't work, let's examine what happens when you execute the following code:

```
$(document).ready(funct());
```

First `funct()` is executed. This might or might not return something. If it would to have something like `return 1` in it, this would be supplied as argument to `$(document).ready( ... )`. In this case `null` or `undefined` is returned. What you want is to supply the function reference to `$(document).ready( ... )` instead. You do this by passing `funct` to it (much like any other variable).

Similary, having an anonymous function will return the function reference to that anonymous function, which then is used by `$(document).ready( ... )`.

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready() takes a function as its parameter, so you have to pass a function to it. 
either do something like this :

```
function funct() {
     return function() {
           $("p").slideUp(1000);
     }        
 }
 $(document).ready(funct());
```

Or as the others said, just pass a reference to the function as a parameter like this:

```
$(document).ready(funct);
```

Comment: why not just drop the `()` as ready handler and save the extra code?

Comment: While that -would- work, I wouldn't recommend to return a function reference by calling an other function, just to use `funct()` instead of `funct`.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Depending on his needs, returning a function might be better (e.g. returning a different function depending on some conditions)